# Material UI on ReactJS: `evt.target.value` not working for `RaisedButton`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, material-ui

I'm trying to submit a value via button click (to be used for changing a state). It works fine if I simply use HTML `input` element. However, if I use [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button) `RaisedButton`, I can't pass a value at all. Please help me point out what I'm doing wrong.

**The function that's called on button click:**

```
changeGameStatus = (evt) => {
    let status = ""
    switch (evt.target.value) {
        case "Start":
            status = "in-progress"
            break
        default:
            status = "ready"
            break
    }

    this.setState({
        game: {
            status: status
        }
    })

    /*when using <RaisedButton>, this.state.game.status returns "undefined"*/
    console.log('new status:' + this.state.game.status)
} /* END changeGameStatus */
```

**The buttons inside `render()`:**

```
/*this one does not send a value at all*/
<RaisedButton onClick={this.changeGameStatus} value="Start" label="Start" primary={true} />

/* this one works, but the look is not supported by material-ui*/
<input type="button" onClick={this.changeGameStatus} value="Start" />
```

Comment: you can directly pass the value ot onClick event like this: `onClick={()=> this.changeGameStatus('Start')}` may be RaisedButton doesn't accept the props `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onClick is not specified as a property for a material-ui RaisedButton and since it is a react component any property that you provide to the raised button is passed on to as props to the component. If onclick was specified the way it was handled in the RaisedButton component would have determined what value you get for the event. Since it is not defined, you are just getting the event from which you won't get the value

You need to manually pass it to the function

```
<RaisedButton onClick={this.changeGameStatus.bind(this, "Start")} value="Start" label="Start" primary={true} />
```

or

```
<RaisedButton onClick={() => this.changeGameStatus("Start")} value="Start" label="Start" primary={true} />
```

and use it like

```
changeGameStatus = (value) => {
    let status = ""
    switch (value) {
        case "Start":
            status = "in-progress"
            break
        default:
            status = "ready"
            break
    }

    this.setState({
        game: {
            status: status
        }
    })

    /*when using <RaisedButton>, this.state.game.status returns "undefined"*/
    console.log('new status:' + this.state.game.status)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works perfectly. If I may add a follow up question, `{()=> this.changeGameStatus('Start')}`, as suggested by Mayank Shukla in the comment above also works. What's the difference between this and `{this.changeGameStatus.bind(this, "Start")}`, and which one should be properly used? I'm quite new to ReactJS, and it's confusing to find different syntax that work just the same.

Comment: I have added both the approaches in my answer, these two are different ways of binding functions , as far as I know .bind(this) returns a function every time and hence I will prefer to go with the arrow syntax approach

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My problem is solved now.

Comment: Glad to have helped, the important part was y your event was not able to give you the value

Comment: Great solution! Glad I found it. Thank you